# Deploying a DACPAC to an AOAG Listener on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, deployment, listener, dacpac

We're trying to deploy a DACPAC to a new server via MS Release Management Studio. We've successfully deployed to other new servers with the same DACPAC with an existing restored database prior to data-tier upgrade. Proving that the DACPAC and deployment process is working.

The only difference is this server has Always On Availability Groups (AOAG) and the target we are deploying to is the group listener. Following the advice from [here](http://pietervanhove.azurewebsites.net/?p=1011):

> You have to deploy it to the Listener, which will in fact redirect your connection to the primary replica of your AlwaysOn Availability Group.
>    The changes will also be transferred to the secondary replicas.
>    The listener enables a client to connect to an availability replica without knowing the name of the physical instance of SQL Server to which the client is connecting.
>    So normally you can use this listener name in the Release Management Studio like another SQL Server Instance.

Having tried to manually upgrading the data-tier application using the listener it states that the target server is not accessible.

Does anyone have a process for this or has had some experience they can share as to why this is happening and what I can do to get past it?

**UPDATE (resolved):**

It looks as though our server was patched which caused a failover to occur. The secondary replica didn't have an account setup for our Release Management Studio user.

Also, our DBA finally chipped in with our replica's being set to read-only.

Consequently, we had made some discoveries, such as DACPAC's will upgrade a database to a data-tier application even if they are not registered.

And although you can deploy a DACPAC to your primary replica as a DAC, the secondary's won't be registered as DAC's unless you manually upgrade / register them. Useful to know.

Thanks to all those that asked questions :)

Comment: Can you connect to AG using listener's IP ?

Comment: Cannot connect to x.x.x.x.

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18107; handshake=14270;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Comment: I can connect using the listeners name, but not the IP.

Comment: Now can you check sqlcmd command that MS Release Management is creating to deploy the DACPAC and see if it using AG Name and not a replica name or the Listener IP ? I believe the parameter in sqlcmd is `/TargetServerName:`

Comment: Release Management is using sqlpackage.exe and the target is the listener name not the IP.

Comment: Can you share more details on this `Having tried to manually upgrading the data-tier application using the listener it states that the target server is not accessible.` i meant exact error message, normally you always use listener to connect to primary

Comment: I connected to the listener using SSMS and tried to upgrade the database on the primary replica with the DACPAC file. Sorry I don't have the error message now and can't replicate the issue as one of DBA's has resolved the problem.

It appears that the server had failed over to it's secondary, which didn't have an account for the Release Management account, and the replicas were set to read-only.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, you all helped with our final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though our server was patched which caused a failover to occur. The secondary replica didn't have an account setup for our Release Management Studio user.

Also, our DBA finally chipped in with our replica's being set to read-only.

Consequently, we had made some discoveries, such as DACPAC's will upgrade a database to a data-tier application even if they are not registered.

And although you can deploy a DACPAC to your primary replica as a DAC, the secondary's won't be registered as DAC's unless you manually upgrade / register them. Useful to know.

Thanks to all those that asked questions :)

Answer (score 0):

This also happens becasue your database recovery setting will be simple. In Availability group or mirroring case it should be full